# Visitor statistics software per user account page

Tags: statistics, lamp

Hi I plan to have a web site that will have pages for local companies. The companies will have a backend to update their details. Essentially in the backend I want the company to be able to see their profile statistics e.g. monthly visitors, unique visitors, visitors per country. Is there a software package that can provide this for my site? LAMP setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics offers a [Data Export API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html) if you want to allow businesses the option to use a Google Analytics profile with your service - there are many other statistics packages out there, however, Google Analytics is pretty hard to beat (unless you want to license a local [Urchin](http://www.google.com/urchin/index.html) install).

---

**Updates:**

> Can I have a Google Analytics profile setup automatically per company?

You could use a single profile (along with advanced segments) to track all activity - for example, if every business gets its own subdirectory (i.e. `/business-name/`) on your main domain, you could filter results displayed in the business' admin panel to include only traffic which matches the business' subdirectory.

> Will this sit under my Google Analytics account?

I was originally thinking that you could encourage businesses who use your service to create a separate profile which could receive data from your website, however, you could maintain a master profile to store the information *and* push data to a business' analytics account (if desired).

Comment: Can I have a Google Analytics profile setup automatically per company? Will this sit under my Google Analytics account? Is there not a limit to the number of profiles I can have?